# Using Boolean in Django Custom Query Set

Tags: python, django

Lately I had came to one strange thing when I was working with Django custom querysets. So, I am using request.GET for passing boolean value to my django view. Then I pass this value to my custom queryset function. It seems weird because it works in case of basic query but not with '__isnull'. Are there any differencies?

**views.py**

```
if request.GET.get('available'):
    items = Item.objects.is_available(request.GET.get('available')) # this works

...

if request.GET.get('order'):
    transfers = Transfer.objects.not_working_is_order(request.GET.get('order')) # not working
```

**managers.py**

```
class ItemQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def is_available(self, is_available):
        return self.filter(is_available=is_available) # this works

class TransferQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def is_order(self, bool):
        if bool == 'False':
            return self.filter(order__isnull=False)
        elif bool == 'True':
            return self.filter(order__isnull=True) # this works

    def not_working_is_order(self, bool):
        return self.filter(order__isnull=bool) # not working
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<a href="?available=False&pg={{ request.GET.pg }}&search={{ request.GET.search }}">Not available</a>
```

**myothertemplate.html**

```
<a href="?order=True&pg={{ request.GET.pg }}&search={{ request.GET.search }}">Not order</a>
```

Comment: `bool` is a ***reserve keyword***, better not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `bool` is not a boolean, it's a string, you can do something like `self.filter(order__isnull=bool == 'True')`

Comment: Ok, but with ItemQuerySet it is working fine. ‘is_available’ is BooleanField, does it make any difference? Because passed variable is also string in that case.